# Improving Python Share Screen

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pygame

I am trying to do a share screen using python and pygame, and the screenshots I take with d3dshot.
Does anyone have an idea How can I make it better and increase the frames per second?

This is my code:
Server - share the screen with the client

```
""" Server """
from socket import socket
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import d3dshot
from lz4.frame import compress


WIDTH, HEIGHT = pyautogui.size()


def retreive_screenshot(conn):
    d = d3dshot.create(capture_output="numpy")

    while 'recording':
        img = d.screenshot()

        img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

        img = compress(img, 10)


        # Send the size of the pixels length
        size = len(img)
        size_len = (size.bit_length() + 7) // 8
        conn.send(bytes([size_len]))

        # Send the actual pixels length
        size_bytes = size.to_bytes(size_len, 'big')
        conn.send(size_bytes)

         # Send pixels
        conn.sendall(img)


def main(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000):
    sock = socket()
    sock.bind((host, port))
    try:
        sock.listen(5)
        print('Server started.')

        while 'connected':
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Client connected IP:', addr)
            thread = Thread(target=retreive_screenshot, args=(conn,))
            thread.start()
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client - get the screen from the server and show the server screen

```
""" Client """
from socket import socket
from lz4.frame import decompress
import numpy as np
import pygame
import cv2

WIDTH = 1600
HEIGHT = 900

def recvall(conn, length):
    """ Retreive all pixels. """

    buf = b''
    while len(buf) < length:
        data = conn.recv(length - len(buf))
        if not data:
            return data
        buf += data
    return buf


def main(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    watching = True

    sock = socket()
    sock.connect((host, port))
    try:
        while watching:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    watching = False
                    break

            # Retreive the size of the pixels length, the pixels length and pixels
            size_len = int.from_bytes(sock.recv(1), byteorder='big')
            size = int.from_bytes(sock.recv(size_len), byteorder='big')
            img = decompress(recvall(sock, size))

            img = np.frombuffer(img, np.uint8)
            img = img.reshape((int(HEIGHT * 0.5), -1, 3))
            img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2).tobytes()

            # Create the Surface from raw pixels
            img = pygame.image.fromstring(img, (WIDTH, HEIGHT), 'RGB')

            # Display the picture
            screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: if you use `cv2` / `numpy` in server to get screen then maybe you should also use `cv2` / `numpy` in client to display it (instead of using `pygame`)

Comment: maybe you should compress it as `JPG` - maybe it will be smaller and it will have to send more data - so will have more time to get more frames. Some tools to share screen make even more complex method - they send only this part of screen which was changed.